# Eloquent: id duplication when inserting new record on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I am trying to insert a new record in my SQL Server database, but it won't insert because the identity is set as 0, which will lead to the duplication exception.

I've created my table id as follow:

`id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)`

Here is my model:

```
class MyTable extends Model
{
    const CREATED_AT = 'createdOn';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'modifiedOn';

    protected $table = 'my_table';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        ...
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $attributes = [
        'id' => false,
        ...
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        ...
    ];

    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    public $validations = [
        ...
    ];

    public $validationMessages = [
        ...
    ];
}
```

and the model observer:

```
class MyTableObserver
{
    protected $dbDefaultConnection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbDefaultConnection = DB::getDefaultConnection();
    }

    public function creating(MyTable $model)
    {
        if ($this->dbDefaultConnection == "sqlsrv") {
            DB::unprepared('SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' . $model->getTable() . ' ON');
        }
    }

    public function created(MyTable $model)
    {
        if ($this->dbDefaultConnection == "sqlsrv") {
            DB::unprepared('SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' . $model->getTable() . ' OFF');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that code but my first comment would be that if you are trying to use an identity column to autoincrement you should not be setting identity insert on.  You should do the insert without the ID and then return the ID after the insert if you need it for your application.


SET IDENTITY INSERT is used when you want to insert explicit values into the IDENTITY column.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the CreateMyTablesTable.up() method. It seems that you have something different than `$table->id();` in there because you shouldn't need that MyTableObserver class at all for database-generated identity columns to work.